# Problems And Errors While Implementing Async Controller Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, threadpool

It seems that I have massive problems understanding the topic regarding async-operations in C# and especially ASP.NET MVC in Controller.

I have a **Controller** for all of my **AJAX-Requests** from my Webpage. for each I have an action. Now I try to implement like a 'notification-system'. I created a class which handles the notification in a Queue, which are selected through a dictionary using the SessionID.

Because I am using **Reverse-AJAX**, the Thread working on the AJAX-Response needs to be hold at the Server. Therefore, I used `Thread.Sleep` in combination with a `while` to check if the queue has elements or not. Here is the part of the controller:

```
public class AJAXController : AsyncController
{
    public async void polling()
    {
        if (Session["init"] == null) //so the sessionID is not changing on every request
            Session.Add("init", 0);
        NotificationQueue queue =
                        NotificationQueue.getInstance(HttpContext.Session.SessionID);

        object responseObj = null;
        responseObj = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (queue.getSize() == 0)
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            return queue.getNextQueueElement(); //behind this is queue.Dequeue();
        });
        Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(responseObj));
    }
}
```

Basically, I don't now what is incorrect with that code - neither I know with is correct.

The syntax is correct, but when I try to use the website, the Server answers with: `500 (internal Server error)`, Message: >>An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked `<%@ Page Async="true" %>`. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it.<<

Do I need an `AsyncController`? The other methods aren't Asynchronous because these are just simple responses.

I tried to use `public async void pollingAsync()` in Combination with `public async string pollingCompleted(string response)`, but the parameter was `null` every time.

My Questions are the above and how I can solve the problem. Is there a better solution, and when yes, how could I implement this?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Not really related to your question, but this seems like a good use case to use SignalR instead of Ajax.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `async void`, use `async Task` instead. `async void` operations are generally fire and forget, as you have no way of asynchronously waiting on them. Also, there's no need to use `AsyncController` when using `async-await`. You can read more about that [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4)

You need:

```
public async Task PollingAsync()
{
    if (Session["init"] == null) //so the sessionID is not changing on every request
        Session.Add("init", 0);
    NotificationQueue queue =
                      NotificationQueue.getInstance(HttpContext.Session.SessionID);

    while (queue.GetSize() == 0)
        await Task.Delay(200);

    var responseObj = queue.getNextQueueElement();
    Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(responseObj));
}
```

Generally speaking, as a side note, you can get around the "polling" experience by using websockets, with a technology such as [`SignalR`](http://signalr.net/) this is even made quite easy and friendly. I'd recommend looking into that.

Comment: probably a `CancellationToken` too, `Task.Delay` etc

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the polling() method gets called now (not like before), but I get the same error.
I could try `SignalR`, can you recommend any tutorials or blogs? The documentation seem to be very extensive and I am running out of time ..

Comment: @Ba5t14n I've modified my answer a bit to use `Task.Delay` instead. Try that instead.

Comment: Okay I've got that working a few minutes ago and now the ressource cant be found. Independent from that I got massive performance issues with that session, try to fix this later (coming back after ~lunch :) )